# AWS Scale Up ECS Services on basis of Response time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I want to use autoscaling policy in AWS ECS Services.
But the catch is that I want to scale up the services using criteria 'HTTP response time' or 'Network delay' which are by default not present in aws criteria.

Is there any way that I can set up autoscaling of ECS service using the above two criteria ?

Comment: "not present in aws criteria" - which cryteria? Do you have any reference to this? Any example to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to create custom metric "Response time" on basis of which I can set alarms to scale up services.
I was looking to acheive this by creating custom metric from logs generated.
Any inisight would be helpful

Comment: Is your service using a loadbalancer? If so there is no need for a custom metric. TargetResponseTime - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html